# Not able to install @mui/icons-material through npm

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mern

**Not able to install @mui/icons-material**

When I try to install material ui icons dependency it got stuck for a long time showing like this:

```
# client**>npm install @mui/icons-material
[##############....] \ reify:fsevents: sill reify mark deleted [
```

I also cleared the cache using `npm cache clean --force` but it didn't work.

How can I come out of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Install Material UI core

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

After installing it install the icons package by running

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

If you have material-ui/core v4 upgrade it to the latest one and for that, you also need to update react to at least v17 because the minimum requirement for v5 of material-ui is v5.

Comment: You can use the npm uninstall --save <Package-Name> command to uninstall old dependencies and install new ones.